# ajax url with dynamically generated page

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-devtools

i want to get seat value called from ajax.

when i see chrome developer tools i can see seat value

what i want which generated by ajax call but when i see source page i couldn't see.

how i can get seat value data using Httpwebrequest or similar other method not webbrowser ?

[image]

is it possible find ajax call url and use this url with httpwebrequest to get seat value?

any tip much appreciate

i tested with Post url in source but no luck

Comment: usually you can fetch the entire httpcontent by httpwebrequest. But there is a chance that the web site contains the handling which do not allow directly fetching the httpwebrequest, thus you couldn't get the html content from website.

Comment: yes..that right...it some tough

Comment: what do you mean by "seat value" ?? each seat has a class. and this class most likely has a JS event bound.

Answer (score 0):

On the network tab of the chrome  developer tools, you can see all ajax network calls.

Edit:

Open the network tab then reload the page

Comment: thanks..i already checked before but unfortunelty i can't see seat data what i want.